# ¿Cómo indicar un modificador de ancho variable en scanf de stdio en C?

Tags: c, formato, stdin, sprintf, scanf

Al usar la función scanf se puede indicar el máximo número de caracteres a ser leídos anotando un valor antes del tipo del especificador %. Por ejemplo:

```
char cadena[21];   // Último carácter reservado para '\0'
scanf("%20s", cadena);
```

De este modo evitas que dentro de cadena se guarden más caracteres de los que puede guardar, limitándolo a su tamaño máximo.

El problema es que el modificador ancho es un literal dentro de la cadena formato de scanf y no sé cómo se puede indicar un valor usando una variable o constante.
En printf existe el modificador * que permite indicar, como un argumento más, el valor de dicho ancho. Por ejemplo:

```
#define ANCHO 10
printf("%*s", ANCHO, cadena);
```

De este modo, se imprime una cadena de máximo 10 caracteres (o el valor que se pase en lugar de 10). Pero en scanf, el modificador * no tiene la misma función, sino que sirve para ignorar la lectura de ciertos tipos de datos. Por ejemplo:

```
int entero = 0;
scanf("%*s %d", &entero);
```

Aquí, al introducir por teclado una cadena y un entero, ignoraría la cadena y el entero se guardaría en la variable entero.

Me gustaría saber cómo se puede indicar el valor de ancho en el modificador de scanf a partir de una variable, no teniendo que indicar directamente el valor como un literal dentro de la cadena formato al llamar a scanf.

Comment: Entonces, ¿Por qué no mejor utilizar ALVs (VLAs) y `fgetc`?

Comment: @NaCl Porque el objetivo de la pregunta no es manejar un array capaz de guardar cualquier entrada (de cualquier tamaño) introducida por teclado, sino limitar el tamaño de la posible entrada introducida por teclado. Con arrays de longitud variable lo que se soluciona es evitar tener que fijar un tamaño en el array en tiempo de compilación, pudiendo crear arrays en tiempo de ejecución del tamaño limitado a la entrada por teclado, aunque ese tamaño limitado a la entrada se vaya fijando en tiempo de ejecución. Pero el problema de cómo limitar el tamaño de entrada introducida por teclado seguiría

Comment: @NaCl Quizás tu intención es ir leyendo cada carácter de la entrada usando fgetc y, una vez se hayan leído todos los caracteres y se conozca la longitud de la cadena completa, crear un array ALV de dicha longitud. De esta manera no necesitas fijar ninguna longitud límite en la entrada y el array se adaptaría a cualquier cantidad de datos introducida. Pero, en tal caso, ¿dónde vas guardando cada uno de los caracteres que se van leyendo? Necesitarías un array auxiliar y, ¿qué tamaño se fijaría a dicho array? Creo que volverías al problema inicial.

Comment: @NaCl Vale, estaba pensando en tu propuesta. Imagino que tu intención es más acorde a lo siguiente: una vez sabido el tamaño máximo de caracteres a introducir por teclado en tiempo de ejecución, definir el array AVL y, después en un bucle, ir leyendo cada carácter con fgetc hasta la longitud máxima. Esto limitaría la entrada sin necesidad de usar scanf. Pero si te fijas, sería más sencillo usar la función fgets, la cual admite como argumento el número máximo de caracteres a leer, y sin necesidad de implementar ningún bucle. El problema es que fgets sólo lee cadena nada más, y no otros formatos

Comment: `fgets` es lo mismo que estás mencionando arriba.

Comment: Aunque en tu caso me iria con una implementación personalizada de `scanf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He visto que se podría usar la función sprintf para obtener previamente la cadena con el formato a usar posteriormente en scanf. Por ejemplo:

```
#define ANCHO 20
char formato[10];
char cadena[ANCHO+1]
sprintf(formato, "%%%hhus", ANCHO);
scanf(formato, cadena);
```

De este modo, se limitaría el máximo número de caracteres leído por teclado al valor de ANCHO.
Me gustaría saber si existe alguna otra forma de poder hacer todo esto sin tener que usar la función sprintf antes de scanf.

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a la respuesta:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define STR(X) STRINGIFY(X)

#define ANCHO 20

char cadena[ANCHO+1];
scanf("%" STR(ANCHO) "s", cadena);
```

Comment: Eso lo limita al tiempo de compilación. La pregunta se refiere más a cómo poder indicar el ancho en tiempo de ejecución. En la solución que planteo con `sprintf()`, ANCHO es una macro, pero podría ser una variable y funcionaría igual.